# Is "Jint - Javascript Interpreter for .NET" reliable?

Tags: .net, javascript, interpreter, jint

I've seen [jint](http://jint.codeplex.com/) in Codeplex. It looks very interesting. Have you used it? Is 0.8.4 stable and usable in your opinion? (production quality?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not aware of this project. It looks interesting, however I'm not sure how many people have actually used it since its only a month old and has only had a grand total of 537 downloads since it was first released. Also the 0.8.4 release just came out today and has only been downloaded 11 times.

You'll probably have much better luck asking this question on the Jint projects discussion forums:

http://jint.codeplex.com/Thread/List.aspx

Comment: Good suggestion. I've posted the question thre: http://jint.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=73101